# Playing a GIF file over camera view

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am trying to add a gif animation over a camera in android. The idea is to get the animation becoming part of the video being taken by the phone camera (something like augmented reality).

I have tried 2 options.

1. Add GIF on camera view, using http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/.

   With this I will need to develop the whole thing in native android
2. Use a third party library like QCAR https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality.

   I was successfully able to create animation over the marker, but in my case I need the animation to be available without marker, something like on a button press.

Has anybody tried achieving similar functionality (adding animation to video or photos clicked by camera)? What is a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: can you pls share how you solved this issue. I am facing a similar problem . Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800352/android-play-video-on-an-inflated-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to find a very smooth way to run a gif on cameraview as it is, but converting the gif to series of images and animating using AnimationDrawable class did the trick

```
//sample code to animate 3 bitmaps (frameBitmaps)

AnimationDrawable myAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
frameBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(frameBitmap);
myAnimation.addFrame(frameBitmapDrawable, 225);
frameBitmapDrawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(frameBitmap2);
myAnimation.addFrame(frameBitmapDrawable2, 225);
frameBitmapDrawable3 = new BitmapDrawable(frameBitmap3);
myAnimation.addFrame(frameBitmapDrawable3, 225);
myImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(myAnimation);
myAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach will most likley not work, because i think Movie uses also a SurfaceView like the Camera and it is not possible to display two SurfaceView above each other.
I think the best way to deal with it is using a WebView above the Camera SurfaceView. 
This way you can load a String containing a basic HTML-Structure including you gif into the WebView.